# rails 3 json custom json formatting

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails-3, formatting, view

I have a collection of @clients with attributes id and email
I want to render this json format

```
 [ 
 {"id":" 1","label":"johndoe@yahoo.com","value":"1"},{"id":"  2","label":"paulsmith@gmail.com.com","value":"2"}
]
```

in clients_controller I defined the following method

```
def search
    @clients = Client.where(:user_id => current_user.id).select('id','email')
    render :partial => "clients/search"
  end
```

and here is the view _search.json.erb

```
[ 
 <%= raw @client.map{|client| '{"id":"' +" #{client.id}" +'","label":"' + "#{client.email}" +  '","value":"' +"#{client.id}" +'"}' }.join(",") %>
]
```

this is working, but I found it fugly...is there a more elegant way to generate a custom json format in a view?

Answer (score 8):

Use a helper function you call from the view to format the output or a library function you call from the controller. Example (of later):

```ruby
def search
  @clients = Client.where(:user_id => current_user.id).select('id','email')
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json do
      render :json => custom_json_for(@clients)
    end
  end
end

private
def custom_json_for(value)
  list = value.map do |client|
    { :id => " #{client.id}",
      :label => client.email.to_s,
      :value => client.id.to_s
    }
  end
  list.to_json
end
```

Comment: For a more decoupled and scalable solution check out [RABL templates](https://github.com/ccocchi/rabl-rails).

Answer (score 6):

You just need use the to_json method. In you case it's

```
@client.to_json(:only => [:id, :label, :value])
```

Comment: this doesn't for the custom output format I need. I clarified my question, any other ideas?

Comment: `@client.to_json(...)` outputs standard json. Can you clarify what you mean by *custom*? If you mean change the whitespace, new lines, etc. then your solution is correct. However you shouldn't need to make a custom output for json otherwise your not talking about standardized json.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [jBuilder](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder) gem from GitHub

for clients_controller

```
def search
    @clients = Client.where(:user_id => current_user.id)
end
```

and search.json.jbuilder

```
json.id @clients.id
json.label @clients.email
json.value @clients.id
```

For more info you can visit [Jbuilder on RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/320-jbuilder)

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://github.com/dewski/json_builder/ to customize your json response in the view and separate it from the controller. It's good when you need to add some "current user" depending attributes like

```
[{:attending => event.attending?(current_user)}]
```